# XMLHttpRequest POST запрос не доходит. Не хватает памяти для отправки строки

Tags: php, javascript, post, память, xmlhttprequest

Посылаю строку больших размеров через

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST",'testing.php',false);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
ajax.send(data);
```

в testing.php

```
<?php
file_put_contents("try.txt",file_get_contents("php://input"));
?>
```

Если размер data примерно больше 6 килобайт, то файл не создается. Почему не создается, ведь XMLHttpRequest() имеет неограниченный размер на отправку через POST?

---

**перенесено из «ответа»**

Нашел лог ошибки, но как исправить не знаю.

```
[Tue May 26 18:14:41 2015] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_exif.dll' - \xcd\xe5 \xed\xe0\xe9\xe4\xe5\xed \xf3\xea\xe0\xe7\xe0\xed\xed\xfb\xe9 \xec\xee\xe4\xf3\xeb\xfc.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
[Tue May 26 18:14:41 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.8 (Win32) PHP/5.2.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue May 26 18:14:41 2015] [notice] Server built: Jan 18 2008 00:37:19
[Tue May 26 18:14:41 2015] [notice] Parent: Created child process 2000
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_exif.dll' - \xcd\xe5 \xed\xe0\xe9\xe4\xe5\xed \xf3\xea\xe0\xe7\xe0\xed\xed\xfb\xe9 \xec\xee\xe4\xf3\xeb\xfc.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
[Tue May 26 18:14:41 2015] [notice] Child 2000: Child process is running
[Tue May 26 18:14:41 2015] [notice] Child 2000: Acquired the start mutex.
[Tue May 26 18:14:41 2015] [notice] Child 2000: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue May 26 18:14:41 2015] [notice] Child 2000: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Tue May 26 18:14:42 2015] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_exif.dll' - \xcd\xe5 \xed\xe0\xe9\xe4\xe5\xed \xf3\xea\xe0\xe7\xe0\xed\xed\xfb\xe9 \xec\xee\xe4\xf3\xeb\xfc.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
[Tue May 26 18:14:42 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.8 (Win32) PHP/5.2.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue May 26 18:14:42 2015] [notice] Server built: Jan 18 2008 00:37:19
[Tue May 26 18:14:42 2015] [notice] Parent: Created child process 1344
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_exif.dll' - \xcd\xe5 \xed\xe0\xe9\xe4\xe5\xed \xf3\xea\xe0\xe7\xe0\xed\xed\xfb\xe9 \xec\xee\xe4\xf3\xeb\xfc.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
[Tue May 26 18:14:42 2015] [notice] Child 1344: Child process is running
[Tue May 26 18:14:42 2015] [notice] Child 1344: Acquired the start mutex.
[Tue May 26 18:14:42 2015] [notice] Child 1344: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue May 26 18:14:42 2015] [notice] Child 1344: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы узнать, почему не создается файл, надо всегда спрашивать об этом РНР. Посторонние люди не могут знать, что происходит на неизвестном им сервере. В то время как РНР **всегда** сообщает, какая **конкртетно** ошибка вызвала проблему.

Чтобы увидеть ошибки, надо всегда ставить урвоень ошибок `E_ALL` и направлять вывод ошибок в лог. Где их и смотреть.

В дополнение к ошибкам РНР надо так же производить отладку собственными силами, чтобы знать - пытался ли РНР вообще создать файл, или до этого дело так и не дошло. Для этого, во-первых, надо не писать код так, как будто тебя штрафуют за каждую лишнюю строчку, а во-вторых, добавлять перед каждым ключевым оператором отладочную печать.

Плюс к этому отслеживать проблемы на клиентской стороне с помощью консоли разработчика.

Comment: Может быть, имеет смысл написать развёрнутый вопросоответ по отладке под PHP, и давать на него ссылку? В рамках этого вопроса немного оффтопик всё же.

Comment: вставил в php error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_log','my_file.log'); Лог не создался. На стороне клиента переменная data существует и выводится, если ее размере меньше 47 мегабайт (50 миллионов байт).